# How to stop overflowing text and make it several lines if needed?

Tags: html, css

The filters at

http://www.carsguide.com.au/news-reviews-search/?keywords=bmw&search-option=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.carsguide.com.au%2Fnews-reviews-search%2F

are overflowing in the left in Chrome and FF. Rather than putting a fixed width for the text there, is there a better way?

How to stop overflowing text and make it several lines if needed? If it goes to several lines, then I will like the number beside it to be vertically centered....?

Answer (score 0):

To stop the overflowing text, add `word-wrap: break-word;` on `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `word-wrap:break-word;` to your links, add this style to your stylesheet:

```
.d a {
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with [this](http://jayeshgoyani.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-wrap-word-in-radgrids-column-or.html) link or below code snippet.

```
.breakWord120  
{  
   max-width: 120px !important;  
   word-break: break-all !important;  
   word-wrap: break-word !important;  
   vertical-align: top;  
   line-height: 15px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `position: relative` to `.refinement li`

Give `position: absolute; right: 0; top: 50%; margin-top: -9px;` to `.expanded ol a em`

Give `max-width: 171px;` to `.expanded ol a`

Try applying above CSS.

Answer (score 0):

**try below code**

.expanded ol a

{

```
color: #666666;
display: block;
padding: 0 0.5em;
text-decoration: none;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

}